# How to generate a pandas dataframe column with pre-determined values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, random, conditional-statements

I have created a pandas dataframe using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ds = {'col1':[1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
print(df)
   col1
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     0
6     0
7     0
```

I need to create a new column, called col2, subject to these conditions:

1. when `col1 = 1`, then we have 5 records. For 3 of those records, `col2` must be equal to 2 and for the remaining 2 records `col2` must be equal to 3. The location of the 2's and 3's is random.
2. when `col1 = 0`, then we have 3 records. For 2 of those records, `col2` must be equal to 5 and for the remaining record `col2` must be equal to 6. The location of the 5's and 6 is random.

The resulting dataframe would look as follows (obviously the location of the values in `col2` is random, so when you try to solve this you might get different record location, but the proportion of the values in `col2` should meet the conditions specified above):

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use a custom function for flexibility:

```
import numpy as np

mapper = {1: {2: 3, 3: 2}, 0: {5: 2, 6: 1}}

def repeat(g):
    d = mapper[g.name]
    a = np.repeat(list(d), list(d.values()))
    np.random.shuffle(a)
    return pd.Series(a, g.index)

df['col2'] = df.groupby('col1', group_keys=False).apply(repeat)
```

Example output:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     1     3
2     1     2
3     1     3
4     1     2
5     0     5
6     0     6
7     0     5
```